# No response received from github ssh randomly

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, github, tcpdump

My `git pull` started to stop working randomly with this error

```
$ git pull
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed
out fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried debugging git to find the problem and saw that it got stuck while `ssh`ing to github

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
...
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''putdotio/putio.git'\'''
```

`ssh` in verbose mode doesn't tell anything relevant. Just gets stuck

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com git-upload-pack putdotio/putio.git
...
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.128] port 22.
```

So I looked at `tcpdump` output while issuing the command `ssh -T git@github.com`

**When it works:**

```
hosted-by.leaseweb.com.33653 > ip1b-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x9f4a (incorrect -> 0x8575), seq 1215933853, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1208500 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
ip1b-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh > hosted-by.leaseweb.com.33653: Flags [S.], cksum 0x937c (correct), seq 970827310, ack 1215933854, win 14240, options [mss 1436,sackOK,TS val 4281013291 ecr 1208500,nop,wscale 10], length 0
hosted-by.leaseweb.com.33653 > ip1b-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x9f42 (incorrect -> 0xf7f5), seq 1, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 1208521 ecr 4281013291], length 0
ip1b-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh > hosted-by.leaseweb.com.33653: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb512 (correct), seq 1:48, ack 1, win 14, options [nop,nop,TS val 4281013313 ecr 1208521], length 47
```

Immediate response.

**When it doesn't work:**

```
hosted-by.leaseweb.com.45295 > ip1d-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x9f4c (incorrect -> 0xcc2f), seq 2556120523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1182830 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
hosted-by.leaseweb.com.45295 > ip1d-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x9f4c (incorrect -> 0xcb35), seq 2556120523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183080 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
hosted-by.leaseweb.com.45295 > ip1d-lb3-prd.iad.github.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x9f4c (incorrect -> 0xc940), seq 2556120523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183581 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
```

Just no answer.

I tried with a different host connected to the same network, no problem with github. All other `ssh` connections from the problematic host doesn't timeout. Successful connection to timeout ratio is approx. `2/3`

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you compared the versions of OpenSSH of the different hosts with `ssh -V`?